# Can I use STM32 boot mode and SD card at the same time?

Tags: stm32, sd, bootloader

The ST32 boot pins are:

- Boot0
- Boot1: Pin PB2

And the SDIO pins are:

- SDIO_CK: PB2
- SDIO_D0: PC8
- SDIO_CMD: PD2

I want to have both SD card feature and boot options at the same time.

Here, the pin PB2 has conflict between both usages. However, boot is just at the beginning. What if I want to keep the micro-SD card inside the slot. Without taking out the card at the beginning, what will happen? And is there any solution for my case?

Comment: Let's say my micro-controller STM32F446RCT7TR connect to SST26WF080B sd-card driver.

Comment: Most likely you put a pull-up or pull-down resistor on PB2 and then when you start using the SD card mode the pin switches to output mode and overrides the resistor